# Как сделать clear (C) для калькулятора на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать кнопку C, при нажатии на которую очищаются 4 параграфа с id = out, out1, out2, out3

```
<p id="out"></p>
<p id="out1"></p>
<p id="out2"></p>
<p id="out3"></p>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function clearCalc() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll("#out,#out1,#out2,#out3");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    items[i].textContent = "";
}
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  min-height:20px;
  padding:2px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearCalc()">Clear</button>

<p id="out">P - out</p>
<p id="out1">P - out1</p>
<p id="out2">P - out2</p>
<p id="out3">P - out3</p>
```

В следующем фрагменте все вместе:

```html
<script>
  function clearCalc() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("#out,#out1,#out2,#out3");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      items[i].textContent = "";
  }
</script>

<style>
  p {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
</style>

<button onclick="clearCalc()">Clear</button>

<p id="out">P - out</p>
<p id="out1">P - out1</p>
<p id="out2">P - out2</p>
<p id="out3">P - out3</p>
```

Comment: у меня не работает((

Comment: kalc.html:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: clearCalc is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: @АндрейСеменченко Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе код из ответа (

Comment: Я всё хорошо скопировал! А куда нужно вставлять этот кусок кода посередине:  p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  min-height:20px;
  padding:2px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
   И зачем он вообще нужен???

Comment: @АндрейСеменченко Он нужен для красоты и не имеет принципиального значения.

Comment: Я не понимаю... У меня просто возникает ошибка, которую я писал выше. Я работаю в Brackets, отличная прога, всё хорошо работает, но почему то эта ошибка всё равно возникает... Может, Вы напишете аналог этого кода? Какой нибудь другой код, но выполняющий эту же функцию.

Comment: @АндрейСеменченко скопируйте к себе весь код из второго фрагмента

Comment: О, уже работает! спасибо! Галочку поставил)